# ThreadAbortException at XslCompiledTransform while concurrent user access

Tags: threadabortexception

I am running an Automation testing through Visual Studio team Server 2005 on my application. The application is a WCF service with Multithreading feature from its BO layer. The userload on VSTS is 2 and the Think Time is 20 seconds(Waiting time after sending one request). But the application is getting a "**System.Threading.ThreadAbortException**" error by doing this. The particular area where the error is happening is 
**XslCompiledTransform transform.Transform(xmlReader, outputXmlWriter).**  By doing this I am actually trying to feed xml(xml is generated after serializing viewmodel) to xslt object(Transform). The "**System.Threading.ThreadAbortException**" error is not occuring while normally loading the application, but occuring while concurrent access of multiple user to the above method at a single time. The detail error is posted below;

- Log Name:      Application
  Source:        Proposal.Service
  Date:          14/02/2014 1:44:20 AM
  Event ID:      100
  Task Category: None
  Level:         Error
  Keywords:      Classic
  User:          N/A
  Computer:
  Description:
  Timestamp: 14/02/2014 6:44:20 AM
  Message: HandlingInstanceID: 279fbd41-c40c-43aa-bc1a-07d3bc950cc8

  ### An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred and was caught.

02/14/2014 01:44:20
Type : System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Thread was being aborted.
Source : System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.1
Help link : 
ExceptionState : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void (System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime, System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator)
Stack Trace :    at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(XmlReader contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(XmlReader input, XmlWriter results)
   at Proposal.Generator.Presenter.BaseClasses.BaseSectionPresenter`1.GetTransformedXml(String inputFileName, Object viewModelPart)
   at Proposal.Generator.Presenter.BaseClasses.BaseSectionPresenter`1.**TransformTemplateUsingXslt**(String inputXsltName, Stream outpuStream, Object viewModelPart, Boolean addNumberPart, Boolean addstylePart, List`1 richTextPlaceholder, List`1 richText, String wordDoc)

Answer (score 0):

You say "occuring while concurrent access of multiple user to the above method at a single time".

Although I see your error comes from `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`, and MSDN states `The XslCompiledTransform object is thread safe once it has been loaded. In other words, after the Load method has successfully completed, the Transform method can be called simultaneously from multiple threads.`, it also states `Note: The Load method is not thread safe when called simultaneously from multiple threads.`.  Is it possible that your code has done just that (i.e. *loaded* concurrently), and that causes the later thread error?